# Morris.js bar chart not rendering hover over text

Tags: morris.js

I am using Morris.js Bar chart. For some reason, the numbers that were supposed to come on HOVER OVER are being listed on bottom left. Does any one why?

[image: morris]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without any code it's hard to give a good answer. But, it has probably something to do with your CSS files.

Morris users this to place the hoover

CSS

```
.morris-hover{position:absolute;z-index:1000;}
```

JS [morris.hover.coffee](https://github.com/oesmith/morris.js/blob/master/lib/morris.hover.coffee)

Perhaps you have some CSS that conflicts with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah true the problem must be with css. Make sure that you have morris.css in stylesheets directory of your rails app and also remember to inlcude css in application.css by adding this line:
 *= require morris
at appropiate place.
Had same problem and was solved by requiring css.