# How to add a hover label to morris bar graph?

Tags: morris.js

I am using morris.js for graph report.

The labels from the graph where displayed only the below graph. I want to display the labels, when i hover it.

Kindly anyone please explain me to resolve this problem.

Comment: This question may also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14294900/945456

Comment: Thanks. It helps to solve my problem..